# How to add to string a new string

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with products.
I need to add to name of products some string.
Example: 
product name "abc1", "abc2", "abc3"
new products name: "Super abc1", "Super abc2", "Super abc3"

Comment: Do you want to `UPDATE` the name as stored in the table, or extract (`SELECT`) the data with the name somehow altered?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you expect us to do all the work? How much will you pay us?

Comment: @Sylvain Leroux I need to update my databse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [MySQL's concat()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat).

If you want to `update` :

```
 update tablename set column=concat('Super ', column);
```

You can even add a `where` clause .

Answer (score 2):

```
update player
set productName= concat("super ",productName)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `CONCAT` function

```
SELECT CONCAT('Super ',columnWithABc) from tab
```